# Grouping spreadsheet rows together in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I would like to retrieve the data from a google spreadsheet and make each row an item.
I found a tutorial to fetch the data and append it to a main div, what I would like to do now is wrap each row and have it's content use the spreadsheet heading as a class for styling.

Maybe an image will help clarify what I have in mind:
[image: the spreadsheet rows turn into items with their respective content]

Here is my code so far (or you can view it in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dendenzilla/pen/NWYjWzR?editors=0010)):

If I understand correctly my problem is that when I append the data it's an Object with all the raw data, so I suppose I need to reference the rows when I loop through them earlier.

```js
const sheetId = "1OVOntRKQ2v8pixijlUPNGfsU4Y96apopzP2seEcevXM";
const base = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${sheetId}/gviz/tq?`;
const sheetName = "users";
// our query specify what we want to retrieve from the spreadsheet
const query = encodeURIComponent("Select *");
const url = `${base}&sheet=${sheetName}&tq=${query}`;

const data = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

const output = document.querySelector(".output");
const outputTest = document.querySelector(".outputTest");

function init() {
  //   fetch data, take the response and return it as text
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((rep) => {
      // console.log(rep);
      //     we remove the first 47 chars and last 2 so we have a usable object in string format
      //     we wrap it with a JSON parse so our data
      const jsData = JSON.parse(rep.substr(47).slice(0, -2));
      console.log(jsData);
      const colz = [];
      jsData.table.cols.forEach((heading) => {
        //       if heading has label
        if (heading.label) {
          //         we populate the array with the propertyName
          colz.push(heading.label.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ""));
        }
      });
      jsData.table.rows.forEach((main) => {
        // console.log(main);
        const row = {};
        colz.forEach((ele, ind) => {
          // console.log(ele);
          //           ternary operator to check that there is a value, otherwise output an empty space
          //           we add '.v' so we return the value directly
          row[ele] = main.c[ind] != null ? main.c[ind].v : "";
        });
        //        TEST trying to have a wrapper for each row
        const pCreate = document.createElement("div");
        pCreate.style.border = "1px solid black";
        pCreate.style.margin = "1rem 0 0 1rem";
        outputTest.append(pCreate);
        //         END TEST
        data.push(row);
      });
      maker(data);
    });
}
function maker(json) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.display = "grid";
  div.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr 1fr 1fr";
  output.append(div);
  let first = true;
  json.forEach((el) => {
    //console.log(ele);
    const keys = Object.keys(el);
    //       this part display the columns heading
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      keys.forEach((heading) => {
        const ele = document.createElement("div");
        ele.textContent = heading.toUpperCase();
        ele.style.background = "black";
        ele.style.color = "white";
        div.append(ele);
      });
    }
    //       this part create a div for each of the Object's element
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      const ele = document.createElement("div");
      ele.style.border = "1px solid #ddd";
      ele.textContent = el[key];
      div.append(ele);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OVOntRKQ2v8pixijlUPNGfsU4Y96apopzP2seEcevXM/edit?usp=sharing -->

<h1 style="text-align: center;">User Data</h1>
<div class="output"></div>
<div class="outputTest"></div>
```

Thank you for reading me and if you can help me please comment any solution or idea that you have,

Have a great day

Comment: Your Codepen demo seem to display the data without issue, so is your question only about displaying it in the layout described in your screenshot ?

Comment: Yes, I can display the data but not group it by row so that every cell of one row is contained in a same div

Comment: So you still want to use `table`, but displaying one product per *column*, instead of one product per *row* ?

Answer (score 3):

I've forked your [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dendenzilla/pen/NWYjWzR?editors=0010) and added CSS class `wrapper` to main `div` in HTML and also added some CSS styling and JS for CSS-classname addition to `cellElement`, constructed from `key`(JS, line 49).

https://codepen.io/yankie/pen/MWVOZNm

Is that what you wanted to illustrate with picture?

Comment: Yes exactly, the "cellElement.classList.add(key.split(/\s/).join("-").toLowerCase());" is a big help, thanks ! Anyway you know how to get all data to show as some of it returns as null ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to display one product per column, i.e. :

[image: Screenshot]

Create one object per `table.rows` containing `table.cols[].label` as keys and `table.rows[].c[].v` as values :

```js
const products = data['rows'].map(
    row => row['c'].reduce(
        (
            product,
            { 'v': value },
            index
        ) => ({
            ...product,
            [data['cols'][index]['label']]: value
        }),
        {}
    )
);
```

Which outputs :

```json
[
    {
        "Product name": "Javel",
        "Product price": 10,
        "Product reduction": 5
    },
    {
        "Product name": "Ariel",
        "Product price": 984,
        "Product reduction": 552
    },
    {
        "Product name": "M&Ms",
        "Product price": 1.29,
        "Product reduction": 0
    },
    {
        "Product name": "Padlock",
        "Product price": 10,
        "Product reduction": null
    },
    {
        "Product name": "door frame",
        "Product price": 100,
        "Product reduction": null
    }
]
```

Then, create one `th` inside a `tr` for each key, and one `td` in the same `tr` for each value :

```js
for(const product of products){
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(product)){
        let rowElement = document.querySelector(`tr[data-key="${key}"]`);
        if(!rowElement){
            rowElement = document.createElement('tr');
            rowElement.setAttribute('data-key', key);
            const headerElement = document.createElement('th');
            headerElement.textContent = key;
            rowElement.appendChild(headerElement);
            tableElement.appendChild(rowElement);
        }
        const columnElement = document.createElement('td');
        columnElement.textContent = value;
        rowElement.appendChild(columnElement);
    }
}
```

Which outputs :

```html
<table>
    <tr data-key="Product name">
        <th>Product name</th>
        <td>Javel</td>
        <td>Ariel</td>
        <td>M&amp;Ms</td>
        <td>Padlock</td>
        <td>door frame</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key="Product price">
        <th>Product price</th>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>984</td>
        <td>1.29</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key="Product reduction">
        <th>Product reduction</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>552</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4xdh17g/1/)

Comment: This is great and a huge help, I tried to get the null to actually return the data as I'd like to use links and other type of information in the final product but couldn't, anyway you could help ?

Comment: Only empty cells return `null` values. I think any data type should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not at the moment, if you have any idea whether it's coming from the fetch or the google spreadsheet I'm all ears!
Thank you for the help so far :)

Comment: I don't see any other type than string and number in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Some cells don't return their data, if you look at my fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/dendenzilla/t28do19a/44/) you'll see the padlock reduction returns null, and when I try to add another column it breaks the entire fiddle with the error stating "Cannot destructure property 'v' of 'object null' as it is null."

Comment: Sorry for double comment but I noticed it only breaks the fiddle if I have cells AFTER the ones returning "null". 
It seems to me to be an "string where numbers are expected" problem but I cannot figure how to either convert all of the values to string or accept any kind of data (I also plan to use URLs). Any help appreciated, with this solved I could accept this as a final answer